# Separating SQL COUNT results into separate columns

Tags: php, mysql

I am facing an issue where the `COUNT` function is not getting me the expected results. This is my current SQL table;

[image: http://imgur.com/18b0w3J] .

My SQL statement is:

```
SELECT 
    comments.videoID, video.title,COUNT(comments.comment)
FROM comments
INNER JOIN video on comments.videoID = video.videoID
```

I am currently getting this output from my database:

[image]

I would like to change this where an additional column will be included to count the total number of comments for each `videoID`. I am currently getting a total of 4 comments for both videos, three for `videoID = 1` and one for `videoID = 2`.

I want to split the `COUNT(comments.comment)` column into two separate columns for each `videoID`.

Comment: Please edit images into the question.

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server? Please use the correct RDBMS tag.

Comment: Your count probably needs a 'GROUP BY'

Comment: imgur is blocked at many locations

Comment: do you really have a column named `COUNT(comments.comment)`? I don't get that output http://imgur.com/xabm8yS - If so, that isn't a good idea.

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Use conditional aggregation: `SELECT
 comments.videoID,
 video.title,
 COUNT(CASE WHEN comments.videoID = 1 THEN comments.comment END) AS comment1,
 COUNT(CASE WHEN comments.videoID = 2 THEN comments.comment END) AS comment2
FROM comments 
INNER JOIN video ON
 comments.videoID = video.videoID
GROUP BY
 comments.videoID, video.title`

Comment: Hey there, my bad, didn't know imgur was blocked in other places. Edited the pictures as per requested, hope it helps!

Comment: Do you really want a different column for each video ID? Having a different row for each one will be much easier to produce and to work with.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you just forgot `GROUP BY` in your query. So try this:

```
SELECT 
    comments.videoID, video.title,COUNT(comments.comment)
FROM comments
INNER JOIN video on comments.videoID = video.videoID
GROUP BY comments.videoID
```